# Joomla edit superuser 500 internal server error

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I can edit other users but when trying to edit the built in super user in order to add 2 factor authentication I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by edit? I'm not sure this is a programming question. You may want to ask on [joomla.se]

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly seems to be resolved with permission changes ie selinux.

sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html

use at own risk